# Como instalar a ZFTool (windows, linux)

Tags: linux, windows, zend, framework, linha-de-comando

Como instalar a zftool no windows e no linux?

Comment: Não é uma pergunta. Você deve apresentar o problema como pergunta e resposta. Escreva aqui uma pergunta e depois adicione a resposta abaixo. Você mesmo pode adicionar uma resposta para sua pergunta.

Comment: pessoalmente achei desnecessário mas...

Comment: Você está com dúvida em alguma parte do processo de instalação do ZFtool ou está fazendo o processo corretamente e mesmo assim está dando errado? Porque caso não saiba nada sobre o assunto o ideal é procurar um tutorial antes

Comment: @ErlonCharles Veja a edição da pergunta. Ele teve problemas na instalação e quis compartilhar a solução, mas tinha feito como um post num fórum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha solução

1. Criar uma pasta onde ficara o zftool no meu caso escolhi `c:\server\zftool`
2. Fazer o download do `zftool.phar` em  http://packages.zendframework.com/zftool.phar
   e colocar dentro da pasta acima
3. Ainda dentro da pasta, criar um arquivo chamado `zf2.bat`

   > @echo off
   >
   > php C:\server\zftool\zftool.phar %*
4. Adicionar o caminho da pasta no path do windows

   > Menu Iniciar> Computador > Botão Direito > Propriedades > Configurações Avançadas do Sistema > Aba 'Avançado' >
   >   Variáveis de ambiente
   >
   > Na coluna Variável procure por 'Path' e click em editar e coloque no final `;C:\server\zftool`

   ### Obs*

   Caso o seu `php.exe` não esteja no  `path` não vai funcionar.  No meu caso `php.exe`     está em 
   `C:\server\Zend\ZendServer\bin`,  logo o passo 4 acima ficaria assim

   > ;C:\server\Zend\ZendServer\bin;C:\server\zftool
5. Reiniciar o computador.
6. No terminal digite

   > C:>zf2 --version
7. A saida deverá ser algo como:

   > ZFTool - Zend Framework 2 command line Tool
   >
   > The application in this folder is using Zend Framework 2.2.5

Answer (score 2):

Já que o tópico é sobre zend por que não para o Linux também?

Para Linux(versões baseadas no Debian):

Inicie o terminal e navegue até o diretório raiz do seu servidor(no meu caso /var/www):

```
$ cd /var/www

$ git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git --recursive nomedoseuprojeto
```

Para instalar o git no terminal (Sistemas baseados no Debian):

```
    $ sudo apt-get install git 
    //ou
    $ sudo aptitude install git
```

Acessar o diretório/pasta do skeleton que clonamos com o git

```
$ cd nomedoseuprojeto
$ php composer.phar self-update
$ php composer.phar install
$ php composer.phar require zendframework/zftool:dev-master
```

Dentro do diretório vendor/bin temos o arquivo zf.php. Ele é a zftool. 
Para executar:

```
$ /var/www/nomedoseuprojeto/vendor/bin/zf.php version
```

Pode-se criar um link simbólico para facilitar

```
$ sudo ln -s /var/www/nomedoseuprojeto/vendor/bin/zf.php /bin/zf
```

E para executar basta estar na pasta de algum projeto do zend. Seguindo este post seria:

```
  $ cd /var/www/nomedoseuprojeto/ 
  $ zf version
```

Será exibido algo como:

> ZFTool - Zend Framework 2 command line Tool The application in this
>   folder is using Zend Framework 2.2.0dev

Digite zf para listar as informações básicas.